# Translate a label for checkout page "ZIP/POSTAL CODE" to just "POST CODE" : Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, translate

does anyone know if there is a way to create a label for the checkout on teh admin panel? we need to change the standard text "ZIP/POSTAL CODE" to just "POST CODE" at teh checkout.

I am new on this, thanks for your help.

Regards

Rodrigo

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in any of the third party extension

you need to create one one folder name i18n and create file en_US.csv
en_US is the language code its depend on your language code

and write like this https://drops.meetanshi.com/JYpeNa

you need to change value to ZIP/POSTAL CODE and POST CODE

second method is to enable translate inline and change the word that you want to change
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html